# URL encode a Textfield text for an API request

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift to write my first iOS app. Trying to request from a custom API and the text field value is not URL encoded is what is failing. I have tried

```
var search_term = search.text;    
var encoded_term = search_term.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
```

But this fails when concatenating with the API url say a string and uINT8 can't be concatenated.

Here is the rest of the code after those two lines.

```
var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(); 
request.URL = NSURL(string: url); request.HTTPMethod = "GET";       
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(),   
completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in    
   println(response); 
   println(error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url : String = "http://myAPI.com?q=";    
var search_term = search.text;    
var encoded_term = search_term.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
url = url + encoded_term!;
```

This allows the concatenation to be done and used with the above function.